# Group messages in threads in PHP

Tags: php, threaded-comments

I have an array of messages with their references to parent message(s), it looks something like this:

```
array (
  'm1' => array ('m9'),
  'm5' => array ('m3', 'm4', 'm2'),
  'm2' => array ('m1'),
  'm3' => array ('m2', 'm1', 'm8'),
  'm6' => array ('m7'),
  'm4' => array ('m3', 'm2'),
)
```

Keys of this array are message IDs and values are references to **zero or more** parent IDs (in any order). Order of IDs can be random and it is not guaranteed that referenced parent ID is in given message set.

What I need to do is to group those messages in a 'threaded view'. So basically I need to transform this array into something like this:

```
array(
  'm1' => array('m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5'),
  'm6' => array('m6')
);
```

Every message should be assigned to a thread grouped by top-level message. Message is considered to be top-level when it has no reference to parent or when referenced parent not exists in set.
Messages 'm1' and 'm6' are top-level because 'm9' and 'm7' are not in the given set. Message 'm3' is in a 'm1' thread despite a reference to non-existing 'm8' - it has other existing parents which links it to 'm1'.

My question is how to do it, and how to do it efficiently? Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

What I came up with is to first reverse those relations, so it becomes:

```
array (
  'm9' => array ('m1'), # this would be rejected
  'm3' => array ('m5', 'm4'),
  'm4' => array ('m5'),
  'm2' => array ('m5', 'm3', 'm4'),
  'm1' => array ('m2', 'm3'),
  'm8' => array ('m3'), # this would be rejected
  'm7' => array ('m6'), # this would be rejected
)
```

Then I would add keys 'm6' and 'm5' with no children as they exist in input keys but not in the transformed array.

Now I have every relation parent => children that can be found in the input data. After comparing keys of this array with input array I can reject keys 'm9', 'm8' and 'm7' as non-existing.

Finally the array would look like this:

```
array (
  'm3' => array ('m5', 'm4'),
  'm4' => array ('m5'),
  'm2' => array ('m5', 'm3', 'm4'),
  'm1' => array ('m2', 'm3'),
  'm6' => array(),
  'm5' => array()
)
```

What I need to do now is to somehow flatten this structure. I need to find every parent *p1* that is also a child of another parent *p2* and append *p1* children to *p2* children. 
I don't know how to do it in another way than iterating over and over again those arrays, but that's not an option here.

Comment: Not sure I understand your application but having many parents of single message looks kinda odd for me. Usually its opposite - single parent has many childs

Comment: BTW, it’s impossible to retrieve an order of messages in the queue by this input data.

Comment: Well, any message can have parent reference to any previous messages in given thread and that is not up to me. Order of messages doesn't really matter here, all I need is to create relation top-parent => children.

Comment: If you're building a comments system (and not just asking a theoretical question), why not just add column called "thread_id" and make your query a lot simpler? whenever someone posts a new comment, if it's a reply to another comment, use that comment's "thread_id", if it's the first comment, set thread_id equal to the comment's own id.

Comment: That's not a comments system nor a theoretical question. I have input data in described format from an external system and I need to deal with it. Eventually it would be stored in some normal structure, of course, but first I need to parse that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed like an interesting challenge for me. What I achieved so far:

First of all, one might get rid of orphans:

```
$a = array (
  'm1' => array ('m9'),
  'm5' => array ('m3', 'm4', 'm2'),
  'm2' => array ('m1'),
  'm3' => array ('m2', 'm1', 'm8'),
  'm6' => array ('m7'),
  'm4' => array ('m3', 'm2'),
);

$f = array_map(function($v) use (&$a) {
  $k = key($a); next($a);
  $vals = array_filter($v, function($el) use ($a) {
    return isset($a[$el]);
  });
  return empty($vals) ? [$k] : $vals;
}, $a);
```

The latter gives an array mapping *parents* to *arrays of children*.

Assuming you have your favorite `array_flatten` function on hand:

```
function array_flatten($array, $return) {
  for($x = 0; $x <= count($array); $x++) {
    if(isset($array[$x]) && is_array($array[$x])) {
      $return = array_flatten($array[$x], $return);
    } else {
      if(isset($array[$x])) {
        $return[] = $array[$x];
      }
    }
  }
  return $return;
}
```

now we could use the function below to walk up the tree:

```
function resolve_parents(&$f) {
  array_walk($f, function(&$v, $k) use(&$f) {
    if(!is_array($v)) { // great! that’s what we needed
      $f[$k] = $v; 
    } else if(count($v) > 1) { // many children left
      $f[$k] = array_unique(
                 array_flatten(
                   array_map(function($v) use(&$f) { 
                     return $f[$v]; 
                   }, $v), 
                 array())
               );
    } else {  // great, one child left, store it as result
      $f[$k] = $v[0];
    };  
  }); 
}
```

Well, it gives us the resolution for one step up. By running it as many times as needed (check for that there are no `array` as values ⇒ everything is resolved):

```
function check_result($arr) {
  return array_reduce($arr, function($memo, $v) { 
    return $memo = $memo && !is_array($v); }, true);
}
while(!check_result($f)) resolve_parents($f);
```

we will finally yield an array:

```
// Array
// (
//    [m1] => m1
//    [m5] => m1
//    [m2] => m1
//    [m3] => m1
//    [m6] => m6
//    [m4] => m1
// )
```

Which is apparently the answer to your question.

Unfortunately, the way above is neither elegant nor proven to be efficient. I just left it here in case the code might hint you.

If you have any questions, don’t hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I needed. I came up with even more inelegant solution - much more iterative, more code, but the results are the same and execution times for about 100 message dataset are pretty much the same, so probably I'll end up switching partially to your solution. Maybe later I'll find a way to optimize it a little. Thanks again.